# Como trocar o valor do checkbox com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para trocar o valor do `checkbox` quando ele for selecionado?

Código feito até agora ele me mostra object.

```
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
  var atual = $("#checkbox").val();
     $("p").text(atual); // vamus supor que aqui o valor seja 23
  var troca = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").val("2"); // quando eu faço isso gostaria que ele alterece o valor daquele checkbox para 2
     $("p").text(troca);
});
```

Comment: Você quer trocar o valor ou text ?

Comment: quero trocar o valor alterar 23 para 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você esta trabalhando com seletor ID, o código abaixo é apenas para um checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[id="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val(2);
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="22">OIE
</label>
```

Comment: obrigado funcionou porem uma outra pergunta se eu quiser passar uma string ficaria assim? `$(this).val("Bom dia")` ?

Comment: @bryant Isso mesmo.

Comment: intendi intao no caso eu teria que usar o `this` esse era meu erro obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Use $(this) para facilitar as coisas e troque id por classes como selector.

```
$(".chkcl").change(function(){

  var atual = $(this).val();
  alert(atual);
  var troca = 2;
  $(this).val(troca); // quando eu faço isso gostaria que ele alterece o valor daquele checkbox para 2
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Veja o exemplo funcional [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/wms7m7ft/).

Se vc usar o depurador do Chrome, verá que o valor mudou dinamicamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]